# Power BI - Expand RetailCalendar table so there is a row for each date between the month statsOn and endsOn

Tags: powerbi, dax, m

[Retail Calendar table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiKVO.png)

Power BI - Expand RetailCalendar table so there is a row for each date between the month statsOn and endsOn

Answer (score 0):

Starting with your table as shown by you and named as Table1. This Power Query...

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"startsOn", type datetime}, {"endsOn", type datetime}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each {Int64.From([startsOn])..Int64.From([endsOn])}),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Custom",{{"Custom", type date}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

will give you output like this... (See the rightmost column, called Custom.)

[image]